# Looking for a 1 to 1.5 mm pitch board to wire connector that locks

Tags: components, connector

I am searching for a board to wire connector such as this

http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/216996350/JST_XH_connector.html

except that the one linked has a 2.54 mm pitch and does not have positive locking. Does anyone have any recommendations on a smaller pitch (1 to 1.55 mm) with locking capabilities?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to do a parametric search on one of the large suppliers sites.

Here is an [example search](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203442%20110160233%20110189651%20110204399%20110128267%20110167559%20110184493&No=100&Ns=P_PRICE_FARNELL_UK%7C0&suppressRedirect=true&locale=en_UK&appliedparametrics=true&getResults=true&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203442&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=203442) on Farnell that returns ~2000 results for wire to board between 1mm and 1.5mm. You can narrow it down as necessary (e.g. contact number, orientation, etc)
When you find a suitable part you can search for it elsewhere by product number if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Molex makes 1mm [Pico-Clasp](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoclasp&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors) and [CLIK-Mate](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=clikmate_wiretoboard_connectors&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors) families.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [1.0mm-1.5mm pitch connector](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/488827968/_059_1_5mm_pitch_bar.html) on Alibaba.